# remove row selection by arrow keys in jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, key-bindings

I have implemented a JTable in JScrollpane. I have added MouseListener to the JTable, so its working fine with MouseListener.

Now my problem is, the row selection changes by the Keyboard Arrow keys(up arrow/down arrow) also and it does not call the methods that I have already implemented with MouseListener. So i just want to remove the JTable selection by Keyboard arrows.

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 9):

Swing components use [Key Bindings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) to invoke Action when a give KeyStoke is entered.

From reading the above tutorial link you should be able to remove the key bindings by using code like:

```
InputMap im = table.getInputMap(JTable.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("DOWN", 0), "none");
```

I'll let you handle the up key.

Comment: For up key I just modified the above as:
im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("UP"), "none");
and its working.....
u r brilliant.....thnx again :-)

Comment: @Raj you can accept camickr's answer to show your appreciation. :)

Answer (score 2):

JTable has ListSelectionModel. You can get it with method getSelectionModel().
Then you can add ListSelectionListener to ListSelectionModel by method addListSelectionListener(ListSelectionListener).